# New Zealand Geocoordinates Duplicated on Geochart

Tags: google-visualization

Google Geocharts seems to duplicate coordinates in New Zealand. Using this sample code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Color', 'Size'],
    [-39.3233416666667,172.68119,1,1],
    [-37.328955,178.019305,1,1],
    [-42.1174016666667,169.043685,1,1],
    [-45.9708383333333,167.715815,1,1],
    [-41.4115416666667,172.45007,1,1],
    [-40.96342,173.016323333333,1,1],
    [-35.3090733333333,175.540301666667,1,1],
    [-34.1865233333333,173.642561666667,1,1],
    [-40.9643016666667,173.015715,1,1],
    [-34.963335,173.928328333333,1,1],
    [-37.0131966666667,177.790023333333,1,1],
    [-40.2057266666667,172.339355,1,1],
    [-44.981545,170.140106666667,1,1],
    [-39.260695,175.11762,1,1],
    [-38.0657633333333,175.641418333333,1,1],
    [-44.9679916666667,168.653268333333,1,1],
    [-41.87978,171.869228333333,1,1],
    [-40.5422366666667,173.954698333333,1,1],
    [-35.610825,174.72943,1,1],
    [-37.613945,178.318931666667,1,1],
    [-45.977555,170.093883333333,1,1],
    [-33.482955,172.83993,1,1],
    [-42.0265716666667,171.297201666667,1,1],
    [-40.7790166666667,173.082521666667,1,1],
    [-37.753235,178.31691,1,1],
    [-36.39364,178.314605,1,1],
    [-37.994665,176.861951666667,1,1],
    [-38.0631616666667,174.97854,1,1],
    [-36.078785,177.529348333333,1,1],
    [-38.9196066666667,177.873603333333,1,1],
    [-35.8661633333333,174.189336666667,1,1],
    [-36.3283583333333,177.802486666667,1,1],
    [-37.11242,175.957198333333,1,1],
    [-39.4010083333333,172.686688333333,1,1],
    [-42.4813616666667,171.659536666667,1,1],
    [-36.0120516666667,177.352293333333,1,1],
    [-39.00966,172.821693333333,1,1],
    [-41.19823,171.576271666667,1,1],
    [-43.3214183333333,169.189333333333,1,1],
    [-40.72748,173.928771666667,1,1],
    [-36.8949783333333,175.739323333333,1,1],
    [-38.6152283333333,176.332703333333,1,1],
    [-43.8388466666667,169.286935,1,1],
    [-40.795765,174.032096666667,1,1],
    [-35.47594,175.32714,1,1],
    [-35.522615,175.389836666667,1,1],
    [-45.9924616666667,167.456761666667,1,1],
    [-41.0157616666667,171.590661666667,1,1],
    [-37.7088433333333,177.385951666667,1,1],
    [-44.011005,167.381986666667,1,1],
    [-39.0939316666667,175.484213333333,1,1],
    [-37.2896583333333,177.063135,1,1],
    [-43.5593016666667,169.25818,1,1],
    [-40.8261316666667,174.117191666667,1,1],
    [-38.60656,176.327905,1,1],
    [-40.2043533333333,172.049511666667,1,1],
    [-33.1701283333333,173.406341666667,1,1],
    [-34.5565183333333,174.425721666667,1,1],
    [-44.724,168.170456666667,1,1],
    [-41.6539816666667,172.22665,1,1],
    [-41.5950633333333,171.51886,1,1],
    [-37.058015,175.14628,1,1],
    [-38.2858833333333,175.126186666667,1,1],
    [-39.1201933333333,175.220498333333,1,1],
    [-40.7023233333333,173.572715,1,1],
    [-35.516825,175.343785,1,1],
    [-33.27494,173.082823333333,1,1],
    [-37.7150316666667,176.496978333333,1,1],
    [-34.6350916666667,174.355116666667,1,1],
    [-41.8437666666667,171.791991666667,1,1],
    [-33.5735683333333,172.862555,1,1],
    [-35.4875083333333,175.42411,1,1],
    [-45.5407983333333,169.494986666667,1,1],
    [-33.5600883333333,172.715323333333,1,1],
    [-34.278335,173.652603333333,1,1],
    [-38.7659283333333,176.895138333333,1,1],
    [-34.0638566666667,174.455745,1,1],
    [-43.6483483333333,169.168591666667,1,1],
    [-40.618075,174.057301666667,1,1],
    [-34.3475683333333,173.555146666667,1,1],
    [-43.998045,171.154305,1,1],
    [-35.3943183333333,175.535488333333,1,1],
    [-36.9281866666667,175.656648333333,1,1],
    [-42.99659,171.588591666667,1,1],
    [-45.3766283333333,169.133755,1,1],
    [-44.961245,169.21398,1,1],
    [-43.90194,170.831255,1,1],
    [-41.5313616666667,171.187071666667,1,1],
    [-34.24905,173.673725,1,1],
    [-34.7706333333333,173.942123333333,1,1],
    [-40.8957133333333,173.014041666667,1,1],
    [-39.1584533333333,172.86749,1,1],
    [-39.1667483333333,172.885035,1,1],
    [-37.863175,176.239815,1,1],
    [-34.7405033333333,174.126041666667,1,1],
    [-35.2644033333333,175.48198,1,1],
    [-34.23176,174.393618333333,1,1],
    [-33.1263,173.388885,1,1],

  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347});
}
```

This is the output:

[image: New Zealand Duplicate Coordinates]

Even if the circles are set to a small side, a bunch of circles clearly exist in both places. It seems as if the rightmost part of Russia is duplicated too.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a consequence of the map projection used (Mercator), which ends up with areas being duplicated on the left and right sides.  There is an experimental option for changing the map projection in the works now, and you can test some of it with the `projection` option.  Currently, there are 4 projections available: 'mercator', 'albers', 'lambert', and 'kavrayskiy-vii'.  [Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) and [Kavrayskiy-vii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kavrayskiy_VII_projection) are "normal" map projections, while [Albers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection) and [Lambert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection) are highly specialized projections.

The `projection` option is undocumented, but seems to have a structure like this:

```
projection: {
    name: 'lambert',
    parallels: [23, 56],
    origin: {
        lat: 45,
        lng: 0
    }
}
```

You'll have to play around with it to see what you can make work for you.

Comment: With the default options, all maps show the same duplicated coordinates. While I may be able to play around with the options, it still isn't an elegant solution (I would rather not need to change the projections). Are you sure this is related to the projection, and not to Google wanting to keep both the US and Russia whole?

Comment: Normally, Mercator projections would not show duplicate landmasses on each side of the map, so you are probably correct in saying that Google didn't want to cut off chunks of the US or Russia.  I'm not sure that there is any way to avoid that problem without using other projections (or using a different set of coordinates for the center of the map, if you can get those to work - I tried with the Mercator projection and couldn't get it to change the origin).

Answer (score 1):

Although this is quite old now, I just faced the same issue.
My solution was to place the New Zealand marker a little bit further west using an if-statement, like so:

```
data.addRow([{ v:"Queenstown" , "New Zealand" }, 2 , 'Here some data' ]);
```

while all the other markers are placed in the countries' center:

```
data.addRow(["Switzerland", 2 , 'Here some data' ]);
```

Hope this helps!